# black background in android rss feed

Tags: android

I have pulled an rss feed in to my android app, displaying each item in a row and then those within a listview. The problem I'm getting is that there's a black background behind the feed items which I cant seem to get rid of, even using transparent for background. I've definately narrowed it down to being the feed items themselves rather than the listview as for that I have a background. See my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter_icon">

        </ImageView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listtitle"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:maxLines="2" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listpubdate"
        android:textSize="14px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [See This...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:background="@android:color/white"` or whatever you want for the outer most `LinearLayout` in your list item layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in your listview

Comment: add this line to your listview android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: tried that too Maulikm, seems like there's some formatting coming from the

Comment: urika finally found it, setBackground was being applied in the java, removed and hey presto wahay

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000?